# Не работает hover с pointer-events: none

Tags: css, html5

```
pointer-events: none
```

Мне необходим для того, чтобы элемент не выделялся цветом при клике. Но так же перестает работать hover.

Вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтоб и pointer-events: none был выставлен и hover работал?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятно о чём речь, добавьте хоть код.. Без этих уточнений ответ один - никак, `pointer-events: none` отключит таргет для мыши, ховер и клик не работают для элемента с данным правилом.

Comment: А почему он выделяется и зачем нужно что бы он не выделялся? Сильно подозреваю что вы  хотите сделать плохо для доступности…

Comment: Добавил скриншёт того момента, когда при клике по элементу, элемент подсвечивается синим. Это не hover, браузер по умолчанию подсвечивает элемент при клике.  pointer-events: none убирает это, но с ним так же перестает работать hover. background: none; не спасает...

Answer (score 1):

На скриншоте больше похоже на выделение текста, чтобы его отключить есть правило `user-select: none;`

```css
p > span {
  color: green;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  cursor: text;
}

p > span:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Текст можно выделять, <span>кроме этой части</span></p>
```